# Firebug launches when I start Firefox

Tags: firefox, firebug

I think I fat-fingered some setting. Now when I launch Firefox, or when I visit some web sites such as this one, Firebug also starts. I want to keep Firebug, I just don't want it to launch every time I visit a new site.

[image: Firebug Auto-launch]How do I disable auto-launch of Firebug?

I'm using FF17.0.1 and Firebug 1.11.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you launch Firebug on another webpage of this site?

If so, you may be interested in disabling the "Activate For Same origin URLs" option:

[image: "Activate For Same origin URLs" option]

---

Edit: Maybe you're looking for this solution: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/firebug/FqyLROFxKFo

Right-click on the Firebug logo (on the top-right corner), and check that the "On for all web pages" option is disabled:

[image: "On For All Web Pages" Option]

Answer (score 0):

Try Firebug 1.5a21, http://getfirebug.com/releases. Its a know bug and they dont know why it does that.

Also Ive heard that after reinstalling it it will work for a while but thats more of a workaround

Comment: I am interested if you have the link to the issue :)

Comment: sorry I cant find the forum I read this on :/

Comment: Not a problem :). Maybe is this that one? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/firebug/FqyLROFxKFo

Comment: @fflorent It looks like it but I dont remember for sure